Explicit Bound in Draganić's Hamiltonicity Result?
Earlier this year, Draganić et al published a remarkable piece of work that resolved Krivelevich and Sudakov's conjecture on the Hamiltonicity of expanders. Here's the abstract:

An n-vertex graph G is a C-expander if |N(X)| ≥ C|X| for every X ⊆ V (G) with |X| < n/2C and there is an edge between every two disjoint sets of at least n/2C vertices. We show that there is some constant C > 0 for which every C-expander is Hamiltonian. In particular, this implies the well known conjecture of Krivelevich and Sudakov from 2003 on Hamilton cycles in (n, d, λ)-graphs. This completes a long line of research on the Hamiltonicity of sparse graphs, and has many applications.

Is any explicit bound known for C?  (That is, independent of n, d, λ?)
